# Setting child (nested) view model to null in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have defined my viewModels as follows:

```
var uiViewModel = {
    updateLive: ko.observable(true),
    sendEnabled: ko.observable(true)
};

var JobViewModel = function () {
    this.ID = ko.observable();
    this.EndedAt = ko.observable();
    this.StartedAt = ko.observable();
};

var viewModel = {
    ui: uiViewModel,
    job: new JobViewModel()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// Callback function from AJAX call
var _ResultLastJob = function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
        if (result.job == "null") {
            // What happens if returned job object is null?
            viewModel.job = null;
            // OR reset the object
            //viewModel.job.ID(null);
            //viewModel.job.StartedBy("");
        }
        else {
            var jobData = JSON.parse(result.job);
            if (viewModel.job == null) {
                // If job was null create a new one, 
                //  however, this will not be bound to KO
                var newJob = new JobViewModel();
                viewModel.job = newJob;
            }
            ko.mapping.fromJS(jobData, {}, viewModel.job);
        }
    }
}

// Somewhere I call to get result, this is called periodically on the same page
$.get(url, _ResultLastJob);
```

I periodically call ajax function to fetch value for job. And on the callback I will set the value for job. However during some of the fetch calls I could get `null` value for job view model. What is the best way to deal with this situation? Should I set `job=null` (Then I lose the bound object I think) or I need to reset the view model values manually and detect in UI that no object was returned for `job` view model.

Any other ways to solve this? I am new to Knockout.

*EDIT:*
Here is a list of results during periodic fetch and I need to update my view model based on this.

```
|Request | result   |
 -------------------
| 1      | non-null |
| 2      | non-null |
| 3      | null     |
| 4      | null     |
| 5      | non-null |
```

Comment: Show compelete code of you viewModels, for me unclear, how do you get data for job view model!?

Comment: View model was complete as I posted it. But I have added code for the callback function where I need to update the view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can sugest you always create `JobViewModel`, but initialize it in `ResultLastJob` method. When the data, recived from server will be null, `JobViewModel` will be initialized with default values. The main advantage of this solution is one logic on view (you shouldn't to add any checks for `JobViewModel` is not null, etc):

```
var UiViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.updateLive = ko.observable(true);
    self.sendEnabled = ko.observable(true);
};

var JobViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable();
    self.EndedAt = ko.observable();
    self.StartedAt = ko.observable();

    self.init = function(data) {
        self.ID(data ? data.ID : null);
        self.EndedAt(data ? data.EndedAt : null);
        self.StartedAt(data ? data.StartedAt : null);
    }   
};

var viewModel = {
    ui: new UiViewModel(),
    job: new JobViewModel()
};



var _ResultLastJob = function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
        viewModel.job.init(result.job);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I forgot to mention that I periodically call getJSON function. And hence I might get null in 3rd or 4th call. In that case `init` needs to reset all the fields. And that was my question, do I have to manually reset each field or I can just set `viewModel.job=null`.

Comment: No, you can't set `viewModel.job=null`, you should manualy reset viewModel.

Comment: Is there any alternative to resetting all the properties?